# HTML iOS form input time not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Alright so i'm creating a website and in a form I have there is an HTML time selector supported by every major browser, I'm having an issue only with iOS where the input is not displayed, it's replaced by a blank space, when you click on that space you can then select a time and after that it will appear. Wanting to know how to fix this. My code is a little sloppy but here:

CSS:

```
input[type="time"] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;    
border: 2px solid white;
padding: 10px 40px; 
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 
rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
background: white;border-radius: 0px;width: 15rem;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input input placeholder="Time" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='time');" onclick='timeChange()' id="time" name="time">
```

I added an onfocus event because at first it didn't show at all then I set it as textbox but when clicked would turn into time picker, works, however when clicking it disappears. You then have to click blank space again as previously stated.

The onClick i added because I thought maybe by setting a value using JavaScript it would appear on it's own, doesn't work, heres the JS code:

```
function timeChange(){
  $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function(){    
    var d = new Date(),        
        h = d.getHours(),
        m = d.getMinutes();
    if(h < 10) h = '0' + h; 
    if(m < 10) m = '0' + m; 
    $(this).attr({
      'value': h + ':' + m
    });
  });
}
```

Please help thanks

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: none;`?

Comment: `onfocus="(this.type='time')` instead of `input type="time"`?

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none; is added to remove iOS's ugly default box for inputs. I already said onfocus="(this.type='time') is because It wouldn't show at all at first so I added it and it says Time but when clicked it turns into time selector. Although now it shows but when clicked opens keyboard but makes the input disappear

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? It just seems like you want a place to automatically put the current time and that you don't actually want the user to enter a time.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I used the Javascript to display the current time because instead it would show as default "--:--: --". I just want it to be displayed on iOS